# helm doesnt use the values.yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

Im using helm to install prometheus operator with stable chart
and it take all the config as expected,

This is the `values.yaml`

```
grafana:
  enabled: true
alertmanager:
  enabled: true
  alertmanagerSpec:
    replicas: 3
  image:
    repository: quay.io/prometheus/alertmanager
    tag: v0.20.0
```

when I run `helm install mon stable/prometheus-operator -n mon -f values.yaml`
everything is working just fine, I was able to see `3` alert manager instances and see the version in the logs `0.20.0`

Now I need to do some configuration that I’ve created and helm chart with `helm create v2chart`

add my config file to the `template` folder of the chart and add the following `requirements.yaml` and run `helm dep update ./v2chart`

```
dependencies:
  - name: prometheus-operator
    version: 8.5.0
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
```

I see now inside the chart folder under the root `prometheus-operator-8.5.0.tgz`

now running on the root I run helm `helm install mon -f values.yaml . -n mon`

and it takes the default charts values and not my `values.yaml` config ( I see only 1 instance of the alert manager with version 0.19 )

What am I missing here?

btw, I see that the config file in the template is configured correctly however it doesnt take the `values.yaml` during installation ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should look like this:

```
prometheus-operator: << this should match the name you are using in requirements.yaml for that particular subchart
  grafana:
    enabled: true
  alertmanager:
    enabled: true
    alertmanagerSpec:
      replicas: 3
    image:
      repository: quay.io/prometheus/alertmanager
      tag: v0.20.0
```

so basically you should let it know that these values are for the subchart, not for the parent chart

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart

Comment: ok I try to do it however I got this error: `Error: error unpacking values.yaml in v2chart: validation: chart.metadata is required
`

Comment: can you edit your `chart.yaml` into the question, please? and `charts/index.yaml`?

Comment: thanks it was my falut somehow I copied the `values.yaml` to the charts yaml

Comment: I’ve one question , assume that I need to create this chart which dependeing on my internal chart (some other custom chart as pre-requesite) how it recomded to handle such case?

Comment: add it to `requirements.yaml`? if I understand the question. you might want to create another question ;)

Comment: correct, but in the requeirement you provide path to something like this `repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com` , how should I do it for internal chart (my other chart…) , should I zip it and put it on the chart with reference ?

Comment: for that you can use either a file path or create a local helm repo and point it to that

Comment: is there a referance how to provide the file path ? thanks a lot!

Comment: more or less: `repository: file://./vendored_charts/nginx-ingress`